# Error in SMTRestart (Mathematica 12.0 + Ace 6.804)

Tags: acegen

I've recently upgraded Mathematica to version 12.0 and I'm using Ace 6.804 Windows (12 Jul 16).
Now I have problems with command SMTRestart[]. I tested this using build-in example: 
AceGen -> Help -> AceFEM manual -> AceFEM examples -> Cyclic tension test, advanced post-processing, animations
When I run this file I obtain the following error after command SMTRestart["cyclic"]:

AceFEM-CDriver: Function H5readInt: Error reading dataset SMTSetSolverCFSolver!.
Description : Input file: cyclic.h5
Version: 6.804 Windows (12 Jul 16) (MMA 12.) Module: ParseH5
See also: AceFEM Troubleshooting Continue

There is no information in manual about SMTSetSolverCFSolver. How can I solve this problem? Restart is crucial for me because of long lasting calculations.

Comment: I would suggest that first you upgrade AceFEM to the latest version. Your version 6.804 was released more than 3 years ago and many things could change since then. For example import/export of [HDF5](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/HDF5.html) format used for storing results was updated in Mathematica 12.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You're right suggesting to upgrade the version of Ace. In fact I have already done it and new problem appears, which I'm describing in new question.